# Stopping Filter Display in Dynamic Data Entity Web App

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic-data

I'm currently experimenting with the Dynamic Data Entity Web App Project type in VS2008 SP1 and after reading many tutorials which offer helpful advice for problems I so far have no need of a solution to I have fallen at the first hurdle.

In the DB I have made my entity model from I decided to start small with a table called "Companies" just to see if I could tweak the display into a satisfactory shape for this small table. The Companies table has a column called "contactid" which leads to a record filled with various contact information in a "contacts" table.

The default created Entity Data Model has guessed that One companies could have many contact records. So it tries to be helpful and add a "Contact" filter onto the page that allows you to see all the Companies that share a particular set of contact info indexed by the "Contact Name" field.

Unfortunately the contact table is a multi-purpose one that also stores contact info for customers and there are about 1000 times more customers than there are companies. So the Dropdown makes the page load time increase exponentially and produces no benefit.

So I'd like to just stop the filter from appearing. Only problem is I don't have a clue how to switch it off. Google is so far proving recalcitrant on the matter so I wondered if anyone in here knew how to get rid of a useless filter.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue. I am new to the Dynamic Data Application template and was quickly impressed by its out of the box functionality. However I noted a few set backs as well, specifically the one you mentioned. Several of my pages took forever to load, and when I disovered that it was caused by the foreign key drop down populates, it took me a while to find a solution. 
The problem is this behavoir is essential to the inner workings of the web site. These foreign key dropdown lists actually drive the result set in the datagrid. (The ddlist is populated, then the default value is set, which raises an event to filter the datagrid.) So the key is to alter this behavoir instead of disabling it. 
My first clue in solve this issue came from an excellent series of blogs I found on the web. [Kudos to Stephen Naughton](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/05/dynamicdata-limit-filter-fields.html)
The concept is to create a metacolumn attribute and decorate the problematic entities in your metatable partial classes. (I named mine DisableFilter)

So, you'll end up with a table and metatable partial class definition similar to:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(InvoiceMetadata))]
public partial class Invoice { 

}

public partial class InvoiceMetadata {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string LiquidatorInvoiceId { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [DisableFilter]
    public LeadAccount LeadAccount { get; set; }
}
```

My newly created attribute, DisableFilter, decorates the LeadAccount (Our Contact table) collection.

Once the column is decorated, I then altered the base behavior of the ForeignKey.ascx control by adding a check for the new attribute. If the filter is disabled, I only populate the ddlist with the default item.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            if (!Column.IsRequired) {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("[Not Set]", NullValueString));
            }
            if (Column.IsFilterDisabled()) {

                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(DefaultValue, DefaultValue));
            }
            else {
                PopulateListControl(DropDownList1);
            }
            // Set the initial value if there is one
            string initialValue = DefaultValue;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(initialValue)) {
                DropDownList1.SelectedValue = initialValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Its not quite what I call a full solution, mainly the value of the filter will not contain a user friendly name. I haven't bothered to resolve this yet, but this should get you one step closer to solving your problem.